# Type definition and overriding

Tags: scala

I'm quite new to Scala and a part of my project ended up with the following design.

```
trait StringService {
  def length(s: String): Int
  def vowels(s: String): Int
}
```

Those methods are used as parameters to

```
def processStrings(operation: String => Int) = {...}
```

Calls like `processStrings(ss.length)` work fine. Now I would like to abstract 
the type of these methods

```
type StringFuction = String => Int
```

The problem is that an implementation like

```
override def length(s: String): Int = { ... }
```

is no longer valid. Of course, I can go with

```
override def length: StringFunction = { (s: String) => ... }
```

but this seems a little off.
What's the proper way? Please feel free to suggest a different design if this isn't a true Scala approach.

Comment: Your original implementation is still valid. Why do you think otherwise? Are you getting an error?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Implementation like `override def length(s: String) = s.length` results in error "method length overrides nothing."
`override def length: StringFunction = _.length` works but I just don't like it for some reason I don't understand. Although if it's the recommended approach, I'll live with it.

Comment: Without the full code it was not clear *what* it is that method `length` was overriding. I may be able to give a better answer with the full code.

Answer (score 0):

Well, there are different ways to do this, depending on the purpose you want to use your type alias for. This works for example:

```
type StringFunction = String => Int
trait Foo { def foo(s: String) = ???  }
class Bar extends Foo {
    def foo(s: String) = s.length
}

def foobar(f: StringFunction)(s) = f(s)

foobar(new Bar().foo)("bar")
```

This works too:

```
type StringFunction = String => Int
trait Foo { def foo: StringFunction  = ???  }
class Bar extends Foo {
    override def foo = _.length
}


def foobar(f: StringFunction)(s) = f(s)
foobar(new Bar().foo)("bar")
```

Strictly speaking, these are not the same constructs: in the first case `Foo.foo` is a method, that takes an String argument and returns an Int.
In the second case, it is a method, that takes no arguments, and returns a lambda function, that take a String argument, and returns an Int.

This difference is fairly subtle though. It does matter for some specific cases, but often can be ignored.

Comment: yes, Scala can infer that method `foo` is of type `StringFunction`. But I'd like to use the type in the trait explicitly. How I can achieve this?

Comment: Method `foo` is really _not_ of type `StringFunction`. There is a subtle difference between a function and a method, that I tried to explain in the last paragraph. You can make a member of type `StringFunction`, by defining it like `def foo: StringFunction = ???` or `val foo: StringFunction = ???` as shown in my second code fragment. This will probably has little if any benefit to you though compared to the other approach. "Don't like it for some reason I don't understand" doesn't really sound like a good engineering reasoning ;)

Comment: Thanks, Dima. I understand the matter. Just was hoping for a magic feature of Scala which can convert a method to a lambda behind the scenes.

Comment: In the first example, the invocation of `foobar` requires magical eta expansion to pass `foo` as a function value.

Comment: @deepdown that's exactly what happens here as pointed out above.